# Fetch single row from two rows of a table with join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I need to fetch a single row out of two rows from a table using a Join or by some other means. I have three tables Account, Account_Perm, and User. Account table has a field called AccountNum, Account_Perm has fields for AccountNum, TeamRole and UserName, User table has User name. Example data is below.

- Account   ==> AccountNum = 1234, 5678
- Account_Perm  ==> AccountNum = 1234, TeamRole=TeamA; AccountNum = 1234, TeamRole=TeamB
- User ==> TeamRole=TeamA, UserName=John Smith; TeamRole=TeamB, UserName = "Casey Brown".

I need to use these tables and my resultset with the columns (AccountNum, TeamRole, TeamRole) should be as below.

```
1234, John Smith, Casey Brown
```

By using Join, I am able to get two rows as 1234, John Smith and 1234, Casey Brown. However, I need the AccountNum, User name for TeamA and Username for TeamB in single record.

Can someone help?

Query:

```
SELECT
    A.AccountNum,
    A.TeamRole,
    U.Name
FROM 
    Account A,
    Account_Perm AA,
    User U
WHERE 
    A.AccountNum = AA.AccountNum
    AND AA.TeamRole IN ('TeamA', 'TeamB')
    AND AA.UserName = U.Name;
```

Comment: `By using Join` ... please include your current query.  Your data is very hard to read and understand.

Comment: <br/>Select      A.AccountNum, A.TeamRole, U.Name
    from  Account A, Account_Perm AA, User U
    WHERE A.AccountNum = AA.AccountNum
    AND  AA.TeamRole IN ('TeamA', 'TeamB')
    AND  AA.UserName = U.Name

Comment: Your data and question are unclear to the point where I can't even guess at an answer.  Do the following: _Edit_ your question to show sample data in tabular format, just as a SQL query would return, and then 2) show a sample output table with the results you want.  You should realize that had you done this in the beginning, you would probably already have an answer.

Comment: That query wont get your expected results. you want two username but are querying for a username and a team role?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am querying for two usernames for two different team roles, but for one account. The account_perm table has two rows (one for each teamrole) per account. My objective is to fetch one row per account, but with two usernames corresponding to two teamroles. Hope it makes sense. I will try to post some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Account table( AccountNum int);
insert into @Account values (1234), (5678);

declare @Account_Perm table ( AccountNum int, TeamRole varchar(100))
insert into @Account_Perm values( 1234, 'TeamA'), (1234, 'TeamB');

declare @User table (TeamRole varchar(100), UserName varchar(100));
insert into @User values ('TeamA', 'John Smith'), ('TeamB','Casey Brown');

--AccountNum, TeamRole, TeamRole) should be as below.
--1234, John Smith, Casey Brown
with cte AS
(
SELECT 
    A.AccountNum,
    AA.TeamRole,
    U.UserName
FROM 
    @Account A join @Account_Perm AA
       on A.AccountNum = AA.AccountNum
    join @User U
       on AA.TeamRole = U.TeamRole
WHERE  AA.TeamRole IN ('TeamA', 'TeamB')
)

select *
from cte pivot(max(UserName) for TeamRole in ([TeamA], [TeamB]))p
```

Comment: your solutions seems to work great. Thanks for your help. One little thing. When there is no row for TeamA for an account, the username corresponding to TeamA is populated as NULL. Is there a way to make it blank?

Comment: Never mind. I got it working by adding the ISNULL clause into the select.